# Filter Columns with Multiple Values

Tags: sharepoint-server, filter, sharepoint-on-prem

is there an OOTB feature in sharepoint 2013 to use multiple values when filtering a metadata column? thanks

Comment: Please elaborate your question. If possible please add code or screen shot where you are stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list view, we can directly select multiple value to filter:

[image]

And we can also go to list settings->click relevant view under Views section->scroll down to Filter section and select “Show items only when the following is true” and type the relevant column name and value.

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, please provide more information.

Comment: did you change any setting on the list? i tried doing this but only one value can be checked, if this matter the columns are metadata columns

Comment: Yes, in the list view we can only select one value for managed metadata column by default. As a workaround, you can use list setting->views to filter. Or enable managed navigation feature, then add key filter in the current navigation to filter with multiple values. about the Metadata Navigation Filtering, you can check the article: https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-apply-metadata-navigation-filtering-in-sharepoint-2013/